# Automatically Iterate Over All Class Members of the Same Type?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code:

```
public void valueChanged( ChangeEvent ce, int index, Level previousState ) {

    Object source = ce.getSource();
    LevelEditorPanel currentPanel = levelPanels.get ( index );

    //currentPanel.columns is a JSpinner
    if ( source == currentPanel.columns ) {
        for ( int k = index + 1; k < levelPanels.size(); k++ ) {

            LevelEditorPanel targetPanel = levelPanels.get( k );
            if( ( (Integer) targetPanel.columns.getValue() ).intValue() == previousState.columns ) {
                targetPanel.columns.setValue( (Integer) currentPanel.columns.getValue() );
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

The actual code is about 35 lines; I simplified it a bit for this post.

Essentially, it listens for a change, it IDs which component changed in instance A of LevelEditorPanel, and then updates the same component in instances B through Z of LevelEditorPanel to match instance A. (Not shown in the code above, it only sometimes updates B through Z, depending on booleans set by the user).

The code isn't too unwieldy for one component. But I have about 50 JSpinners, 10 JComboBox, and 40 JCheckBox in "LevelEditorPanel" that all want to be controlled in the same general way.

The only solution I can think of is to copy and paste this code for each of the other 49 JSpinners, generate similar code for the other three types of inputs, and then copy and paste the code for each of those as well, something like this:

```
if ( source == currentPanel.columns ) {
  //Paste 35 lines
} else if ( source == currentPanel.rows ) {
  //Paste 35 lines, change all references to 'columns' to 'rows'
} else if ( source == currentPanel.speed ) {
   //etc
```

which would be thousands of lines of really difficult to manage code.

I'm looking for a better solution.  In psuedocode, I'd like to do something like this:

```
foreach ( JSpinner theSpecificSpinner defined in LevelEditorPanel ) {
    if ( source == currentPanel.theSpecificSpinner ) {
        target.theSpecificSpinner.setValue ( currentValue );
        //etc
    }
}
```

---

To rephrase the question, I think I need two tools:

1. The ability to iterate over all of the members of a particular instance of a class and look for a match.
2. Then the ability to dynamically reference the same member of a different instance of that class.

Alternatively, I need a novel solution to this problem.

I hope my post is clear.  If not, please feel free to ask for any clarification.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code can be literally translated to Java like this:

```
Component[] components = currentPanel.getComponents();
for (component: components) {
    if (component == source && component instanceof JSpinner) {
        ((JSpinner)component).setValue(currentValue);
    }
}
```